# Ajax calendar control not working based on the CurrentUICulture

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ajaxcontroltoolkit, calendarextender, regional-settings

I have used Ajax calendar extender in my application in which, it is deployed in sharepoint site.
I have set my regional setting for my sharepoint site as "Sweden-Swedish" also, my site has "Select language" option for the end users.
Problem is: whenever anyone choose any of the languages from "Select language" option, it will not have any impact on the ajax calendar control, instead it is showing the day and month names in "Sweden-Swedish" culture.

Immediate help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax Control Toolkit relies on a standard ASP.NET culture detection, which is based on browser's regional settings.

If you see, that other sites are shown with Swedish culture as well, then you can [force it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).